# Регулярное выражение для получения классов body в HTML строке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Нужно составить регулярное выражение, которое осуществляет в строке поиск тега и забирает все его классы.

Есть строка (весь HTML страницы), нужно в этой строке найти тег `body` и вывести его классы. Строка начинается с `<!DOCTYPE`, но `find` и прочие не работают. Поэтому и думал регуляркой вытащить.

Comment: А зачем Вам регулярное выражение? Чтобы получить классы какого-либо тега (допустим, body), достаточно $('body').attr('class').

Comment: у меня у переменной содержащей весь html тип строка. если использовать всякие find или attr то пишет - "is not a function"

Comment: @DexColt find может быть применен, если этот html будет обернут  в какой-нибудь тег еще. Хотя если эта строка начинается с тега `html`, то должно работать и так

Comment: начинается с <!DOCTYPE  но find и прочие не работают. Поэтому и думал регуляркой вытащить

Comment: какую ты задачу решаешь в принципе? откуда у тебя html в виде строки и зачем тебе нужны классы тега из этой строки и почему вообще html в виде строки в js?

Comment: @DexColt, создайте элемент, запишите в его html свою строку со всем кодом страницы и ищите внутри этого элемента средствами jquery ;)

Comment: =)) я использую скрипт для перехода между страницами barba, короче ajax замена контента. При смене содержимого контейнера, не меняются классы body(классы прописываются CMS), но у скрипта barba есть в api возврат строки в которой есть весь html страницы.для корректной работы разных штук cms, нужно чтобы классы в body менялись. Body нельзя сделать контейнером замены, так как по логике макета верхнее меню должно всегда оставаться. как то так =)

Comment: @Visman это велосипед уже + грузить удвоенный контент - бред

Comment: @АлексейШиманский неа, не должно "работать и так". Если просто распарсить с помощью `jQuery.parseHTML` строку вида `"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body class='one two'><p></p></body></html>"`, то  останется только `<p></p>`.

Comment: @DexColt если позволять себе резкие высказывания, то помощи так можно прождать долго.

Comment: @Regent я извиняюсь, если я кого то обидел - ничего злого не предполагал, просто указал, что метод плох.

Comment: @DexColt однако использовать регулярные выражения для поиска чего-либо в HTML куда хуже (в общем случае), чем парсить HTML. Поэтому использовать рег. выражения в таких ситуациях можно только "на свой страх и риск" или при полной уверенности конструкция `<body ... class=` будет единственна в данной строке. Я, возможно, добавлю в свой ответ вариант с рег. выражением, но всё же основной вариант - парсинг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правило, использовать регулярные выражения для поиска какого-либо элемента в HTML структуре - плохая затея. Поэтому обычно пользуются парсингом.

Воспользоваться методом `jQuery.parseHTML` в данном случае не получится, так как при его использовании тег `body` удаляется из результата.

Однако при валидной структуре документа можно воспользоваться [jQuery.parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) для создания полной структуры, в которой уже можно будет найти `body` с помощью `find`:

```js
var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body class='one two'><p></p></body></html>";
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(html);
console.log($(xmlDoc).find("body").attr("class"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

При желании можно обойтись и без jQuery:

```js
var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body class='one two'><p></p></body></html>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
console.log(htmlDoc.body.classList);
```

---

И только если по какой-то причине парсингом воспользоваться нельзя, можно попытаться смастерить рег. выражение. Которое, однако, не гарантирует корректность работы во всех случаях.

В данном примере представленное рег. выражение отработает как нужно:

```js
var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body id='x' class='one two'><p class='three'></p></body></html>";
var match = html.match(/<body.*?class=("|')(.*?)("|')/i);
console.log(match[2]);
```

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ!

Comment: А в каких случаях регулярка не отработает как нужно? Парсинг не пашет у меня.

Comment: @DexColt парсинг валится с ошибкой? Если "да", то, возможно, у вас в HTML (который в строке) есть скрипты, которые не вынесены в файл, а вставлены прямо в страницу. Такие скрипты и парсинг могут быть испортить, и работу рег. выражения. [Пример такой ситуации](https://jsfiddle.net/w89pz0uu/).

Comment: да, скрипты есть, CMS вставляет. Вы очень круто помогли мне, за что огромное спасибо.